# Как установить WooCommerce на свою тему WordPress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно установить плагин WooCommerce в свою тему оформления wp так, чтобы всё работало. Особенно меня интересует вопрос создания шаблона страницы товара. Что мне нужно в него добавить, чтобы потом можно было из excel файла выгрузить все мои товары в плагин и залить их  в этот шаблон, да так, чтобы все встало красиво.

Comment: "установить плагин woocomerce в свою тему оформления wp" невозможно. потому что и тема и плагины устанавливается в ВП. А остальное вообще не относиться ни к теме ни к шаблонам. Срочно учить основы ВП!

Comment: Я просто не так выразился. Просто при установке, woocomerce ругается на мою тему.

Comment: "Не так выразился"  и вообще вся постановка вопроса говорит.. нет, просто кричит о полнейшем непонимании ВП.  "Какие штаны надеть что бы доехать до вчерашнего фильма". Нет, это не упрёк. Это объяснение что нельзя браться за дело, не имеет даже базовых знаний. Их нужно вначале получить.  --- А WC когда "ругается" тут же и говорит что не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно вас поняла. Ставите плагин Woocommerce, да, он будет ругаться и предлагать поставить свои темы.
Копируете папку плагина woocommerce в папку своей темы и там с ней разбираетесь.